# Python app deployment on Heroku results in application error H10

Tags: python, django, git, heroku, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy my Python project to Heroku, I followed the tutorial on Heroku but still get an application error.

```
  (ISproject) Hessas-MBP-2:ISproject hessaaljeri$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 985 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:       /app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/b in/steps/python: line 7: [: too many arguments
 remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
 remote: 
 remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
 remote:        180 static files copied to    '/tmp/build_eb1f0e2e350e841c604cef9887a7c8c2/static'.
 remote: 
 remote: -----> Discovering process types
 remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
 remote: 
 remote: -----> Compressing...
 remote:        Done: 74.8M
 remote: -----> Launching...
 remote:        Released v6
 remote:        https://charitycba.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
 remote: 
 remote: Verifying deploy.... done.
 To https://git.heroku.com/charitycba.git
 2890bc6..116d04a  master -> master
 (ISproject) Hessas-MBP-2:ISproject hessaaljeri$ heroku run ./manage.py   migrate
 Running ./manage.py migrate on ⬢ charitycba... up, run.7297 (Free)
 Operations to perform:
 Synchronize unmigrated apps: crispy_forms, messages, datetimewidget,  staticfiles, geoposition
 Apply all migrations: auth, sessions, admin, registration, contenttypes, app, sites
 Synchronizing apps without migrations:
 Creating tables...
 Running deferred SQL...
 Installing custom SQL...
 Running migrations:
 No migrations to apply.
```

after that when I open it I get this:

[image]

Heroku log file:

```
 2017-06-02T21:43:25.157364+00:00 heroku[run.5045]: Starting process  with command `./manage.py migrate`
 2017-06-02T21:43:25.231039+00:00 heroku[run.5045]: State changed from  starting to up
2017-06-02T21:43:33.626152+00:00 heroku[run.5045]: State changed from up to complete
 2017-06-02T21:43:33.611887+00:00 heroku[run.5045]: Process exited with status 0
 2017-06-02T21:43:46.905298+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=charitycba.herokuapp.com  request_id=112cc8a0-cb4a-4039-bc79-e76980a4a287 fwd="31.203.118.236" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
 2017-06-02T21:44:24.998284+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=charitycba.herokuapp.com request_id=fe3bb21b-b3ea-4ea3-bc45-b0084aad829e fwd="31.203.118.236" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
 2017-06-02T21:45:22.765792+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=charitycba.herokuapp.com request_id=f54d4bac-d8b6-422d-b24a-1f655c6ea2c5 fwd="31.203.118.236" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Check your logs for details and post them here. I guess this is a 500 error.

Comment: I don't use heroku, but what you posted looks like the deployment log, not the app log.

Comment: How does your Procfile look like?

Comment: @BojanKogoj web: gunicorn gettingstarted.wsgi --log-file -

Comment: Can you try to remove the `--log-file -`, that might be preventing the log messages from appearing on heroku, but I'm not sure on that.

Comment: have you added the `.herokuapp.com` in your settings `ALLOWED_HOSTS`?

Comment: @KostasLivieratos yes

Comment: @PacoH. didn't change anything

Comment: Have you found your app logs yet, Hessa? That is almost certainly going to contain the answer.

Comment: @halfer oh my god! I did! it worked! Thank you!! I'm so happy

Comment: Great, well done @Hessa. If you think it would be useful for future readers, please summarise what you have learned below, by clicking on 'Add Your Answer'.

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed it:

in my settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../app/static'),
)
```

'../app/static' I'm telling it to go up a directory and into my app which has my static folder.

and in my Procfile

```
web: gunicorn project.wsgi --log-file -
```

I replaced the gettingstarted.wsgi by project.wsgi 
because wsgi.py is in my project folder.